# How to cache the JavaScript Date object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datejs

I am using [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) to support many cultures in my web app. The problem here is that date.js has code like this.

```
  Date.prototype._toString = Date.prototype.toString;
  Date.prototype.toString = function () {
    //doing something
        return this._toString();
   }
```

when I use another culture file, it also contains this definition. so logically my doc has this

```
//date.js
     Date.prototype._toString = Date.prototype.toString;
     Date.prototype.toString = function () {
     //doing something
         return this._toString();
     }
     //date-fr-FR.js
     Date.prototype._toString = Date.prototype.toString;
     Date.prototype.toString = function () {
         //doing something
         return this._toString();
     }
```

I am refering to both date.js and date-fr-FR.js in my web app.

The problem is when I use the toString function `var d = new Date().toString();` it throws an `Out of stack space` msg, because of the recursive calls. Is there any way to cache the
orginal Date object and rest it back, because i don't want  to remove date.js from doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of including both `date.js` and `date-fr-FR.js`, you only need to include the `fr-FR.js` file to change the culture, which you will find in the src/globalization folder in the Datejs-all-Alpha1.zip file. The fr-FR.js file only contains the culture specific data, and it should override what is already included in date.js, without redefining the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is check whether `_toString` has been defined or not.

```
Date.prototype._toString = Date.prototype._toString || Date.prototype.toString;
Date.prototype.toString = function() {
    //doing something      
    return this._toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only copy the function once:

```
Date.prototype._toString = Date.prototype.toString;
```

The second time you do this, it will copy the native toString function again, wich will then call itself via a recursive loop.

I don’t know if you are actually doing this more than once, bu in the [`fr-FR.js`](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/source/browse/trunk/src/globalization/fr-FR.js) file there are no other toString methods defined so I’m guessing you are adding it manually.

**Update**

If you are including the date.js core twice (which you shouldn’t, just include the locales), you could probably check if the function is present first:

```
if ( typeof Date.prototype._toString != 'function' ) {
    // include date.js
}
```

Comment: I can't do nothing with this, becaue that is in Date.js lib.

Comment: The Date.js core file only does this once, but in your example you are doing it twice, right?

Comment: What i need is catch the Date value first and before adding the second date.js i have to rest the Date so that the second js use the orginal js Date object.

Comment: Are you talking about including the Date.js core twice, and the second times it doesn’t work?

Comment: yes exactly, i am use two data.js with different culture. one i referred in head tag, another one is append to the  doc based on the user selection.

Comment: Why don’t you just include the separate culture js file instead of a larger bundled file? Anyway, see my update.