# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Out of stack space in date.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, datejs

I just dont get it why i get this Microsoft JScript runtime error: Out of stack space in my date.js file....

```
return format?format.replace(/dd?d?d?|MM?M?M?|yy?y?y?|hh?|HH?|mm?|ss?|tt?|zz?z?/g,function(format){switch(format){case"hh":return p(self.getHours()<13?self.getHours():(self.getHours()-12));case"h":return self.getHours()<13?self.getHours():(self.getHours()-12);case"HH":return p(self.getHours());case"H":return self.getHours();case"mm":return p(self.getMinutes());case"m":return self.getMinutes();case"ss":return p(self.getSeconds());case"s":return self.getSeconds();case"yyyy":return self.getFullYear();case"yy":return self.getFullYear().toString().substring(2,4);case"dddd":return self.getDayName();case"ddd":return self.getDayName(true);case"dd":return p(self.getDate());case"d":return self.getDate().toString();case"MMMM":return self.getMonthName();case"MMM":return self.getMonthName(true);case"MM":return p((self.getMonth()+1));case"M":return self.getMonth()+1;case"t":return self.getHours()<12?Date.CultureInfo.amDesignator.substring(0,1):Date.CultureInfo.pmDesignator.substring(0,1);case"tt":return self.getHours()<12?Date.CultureInfo.amDesignator:Date.CultureInfo.pmDesignator;case"zzz":case"zz":case"z":return"";}}):this._toString();};
```

I've placed this in my _layout.cshtml before RenderBody() was called...

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- date range picker -->
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/date.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/daterangepicker.jQuery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

These are the functions inside my custom.js .... i have tried to comment out the two datepicker functions, the result was there were no errors in the date.js then i tried using the other one while commenting the other... result was everytime i click the datepicker...the exception occurs... i dont understand why is this happening,,,, thank ahead :)

```
$(function () {

    // using daterangepicker plugin
    $('#rangeFrom, #rangeTo').daterangepicker();

});

$(function () {

    // using datepicker plugin
    $("#startDate").datepicker(
    {   minDate: new Date(2012, 4 - 1, 30) // it will set minDate from 30 April 2012

    }
   );

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the `toString()`  cause this issue, i already faced this take a look at this 
[Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173425/how-to-cache-the-javascript-date-object).

Comment: how am i supposed to do about this? Should i remove toString() in the date.js file?

Comment: no, make sure you did not have two date.js file referred in your doc for example having the date.js file reference in sitemaster and also in aspx/cshtml

Comment: actually i have a daterangepicker and a datepicker in my page... seems like there's trouble in referencing the date.js

Comment: 'Out of stack space' will throw because of the recursive(calling the same method because of some prototype problem) calls. so try to figure out where and why it happens.